# Using SQL to grab children where the parent & children are both in the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table that contains both parent and children. Now, I can make to separate calls to the table:

```
Select * FROM inventory WHERE subID=0 // parents
```

Loop through parents

```
Select * from inventory where subID=parentID
```

My question is, is there a way to form a SQL statement which grabs the parent and the children that belong to it, so..

```
//SQL Results would look like this
Parent
 - Child
 - Child
Parent
 - Child
 - Child
 - Child
etc..
```

### Update

Now that I know what this is called, here's my attempt, but this returns no results. the id=0 indicates that it's a parent. What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH children AS (

    SELECT id, parent_id
    FROM inventory
    WHERE id = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.id , a.parent_id
    FROM inventory a
    JOIN children b ON b.parent_id = a.id
)
    SELECT id, parent_id
    FROM children
```

Here's what the working code looks like:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, parent_id, dateOn, capacity, status, instructorID, rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC)
    FROM inventory
    WHERE parent_id = 0 AND active='True' AND cID=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.dateOn, a.capacity, a.status, a.instructorID, b.rowNum
    FROM inventory a
    JOIN cte b  ON a.parent_id = b.id
    WHERE a.parent_id <> 0 AND active='True' AND cID=1
)
    SELECT id, parent_id, dateOn, capacity, status, (SELECT count(aID) FROM appointments WHERE id=cte.id) as totalCount
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY rowNum, id
```

Comment: This is called an adjacency list. It is a very common way of storing data like this. The technique to do what you want is called a recursive cte. There are literally thousands and thousands and thousands of examples of how to do this all over this site and the rest of the internet.

Comment: appreciate the response. I'll look around and see what i can find :)

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to find an answer yourself when you don't know what words to search for.

Comment: you ain't wrong on that one!

Comment: I've updated my question to show my attempt. Sadly it doesn't work. What did i do wrong?

Comment: How about a table definition and some sample data?

Comment: Table definition? Not sure what you mean, but the name of the table is inventory and the unique ID is "id". The parent_id is where the record is either a parent or a child. If it's a parent, then the id will be 0. I omitted the other columns as i just wanted to try to get this to work at the most basic level. hope this helps

Comment: Meaning ddl (data definition language) to create the table. Then sample data as inserts. That way I have something to work with. As it is I have to play sql server compiler with no tables or data. Check out this. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161767/discussion-between-damien-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I think I have it figured out now. The `rowNum` in the CTE is used for sorting the records in the final select.

```
;WITH children AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, parent_id, rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC)
    FROM inventory
    WHERE parent_id = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.id , a.parent_id, b.rowNum
    FROM inventory a
    JOIN children b  ON a.parent_id = b.id
    WHERE a.parent_id <> 0    
)
    SELECT id, parent_id
    FROM children
    ORDER BY rowNum, id
```

Second edit using the full query from the question:

To sort on dateOn, you'd just add it to the beginning of the `ORDER BY` clause. Then you end up with this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, parent_id, dateOn, capacity, status, instructorID, rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC)
    FROM inventory
    WHERE parent_id = 0 AND active='True' AND cID=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.dateOn, a.capacity, a.status, a.instructorID, b.rowNum
    FROM inventory a
    JOIN cte b  ON a.parent_id = b.id
    WHERE a.parent_id <> 0 AND active='True' AND cID=1
)
    SELECT id, parent_id, dateOn, capacity, status, (SELECT count(aID) FROM appointments WHERE id=cte.id) as totalCount
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY dateOn, rowNum, id
```

Let's break down the query to see what's going on:

The 'anchor' of the CTE is

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, parent_id, dateOn, capacity, status, instructorID, rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC)
FROM inventory
WHERE parent_id = 0 AND active='True' AND cID=1
```

This is getting all of the parent records from `inventory`, and adding a rownumber that we can use to associate the parent and all children for the purpose of sorting in the final select.

The recursive part of the CTE is

```
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.dateOn, a.capacity, a.status, a.instructorID, b.rowNum
FROM inventory a
JOIN cte b  ON a.parent_id = b.id
WHERE a.parent_id <> 0 AND active='True' AND cID=1
```

In this part of the query, `cte` is the recursive reference to our parent records in the anchor query. So here we're joining the non-parent records to the parent records. We use the parent's `rowNum` so the parent and its children will all have the same value for this field.

The final select statement then returns all our rows from the CTE. We order by `dateOn` first so that all parent/children records that share the same `dateOn` will be together. Next we order by the `rowNum` so each parent will be together with its children. Finally, we sort on the `id`, assuming that parents will have smaller `id` values than their children. If a parent would have a larger `id`, then we could order by the `parent_id` instead so the parent records (with `parent_id = 0`) would appear before their children.

Comment: hmm... i tried that and finally got some results, but it only returned the parents. So i removed the parent_id where clause and it give me everything now, but the info is off... it's repeating parents over and over and not listing the children :\

Comment: @Damien, I updated my answer with the correct query.

Comment: WOW! Two things, i've update my code to include everything i need in the query. How do i order by dateOn. Also, this seemed to work pretty well besides that dateOn part. Can you please explain what you did so I can learn this going forward. Break it down for a dummy